# Vite import CSS with alias in main.ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to replace vue-cli with vite. I have a vite.config.js so I can use alias for imports:

```
export default {
    alias: {
        '@': require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
};
```

Then in my main.ts I try to import my css file (I tried it with or without the `.module`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

import '@/assets/app.module.css';

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

But I get this error:

> [vite] Failed to resolve module import "@/assets/app.module.css". (imported by /src/main.ts)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [those code lines](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/master/src/node/config.ts#L66)

> alias a path to a fs directory
> the key must start and end with a slash
> `'/@foo/': path.resolve(__dirname, 'some-special-dir')`

so try out :

```
 '/@/': require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case. I can now import the css with @/assets/app.css, but it seems I now need to import my TS and .vue files with /@/components/ or VSCode complains.

Comment: do you mean that you have to change every relative path to `@/` absolute one?

Comment: I think this is not a vite issue, but a VSCode one. I need to add a minimal tsconfig.json after all so it is happy again

Answer (score 10):

**Tested**

just wanted to add:
For anyone still looking at this answer you need to add resolve so it work, as documented in the website.
I didn't added the slashes '/@/'
This works for me:

example:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },
```

https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias

Comment: I think this is now true for Vite 2

Comment: Yes this worked. This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 6):

As of `vite@2.1.5` I could solve resolution of `@` and `~` aliases in the following way:

- add [vite-aliases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-aliases)
- modify `vite.config.js` as described in the `readme.md`
- add an alias for the referenced scss file using the `~` alias as follows:

  ```
  aliases.push({ find: '~bootstrap', replacement: 'bootstrap' })
  ```

now `vite.config.js` looks as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { getAliases } from 'vite-aliases'

const aliases = getAliases();

// add aliases to import scss from node_modules here

aliases.push({ find: '~bootstrap', replacement: 'bootstrap' })

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: aliases
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "@scss/shared.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

this allowed me to import scss files as follows:

in `src/main.ts`:

```
import '@scss/main.scss'
```

in `src/scss/main.scss`:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Obviously, if you need to import more scss files from a subdirectory of `node_modules`, sou need to add some more aliases to `aliases`. Leaving out the tilde alias for importing `bootstrap.scss` worked, but it would not be recognized by my IDE. Adding the `css.preprocessorOptions.scss.additionalData` causes the `shared.scss` to be imported in each vue SFC.

Comment: Simply using `resolve: { alias: { '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap') }}` works, no need for `vite-aliases` plugin. Pointed me in the right direction, though, thanks. Not sure why, but `'~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')` doesn't work, for some reason, so you have to add an entry for every plugin referenced into an scss `@import`.

Comment: thanks a lot the answer and @tao comment saved the day

Answer (score 3):

@Boussadjra Brahim answered the original question, I just want to add some insights for other who have problems with VSCode and the vite setup. Here is my minimalistic tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        },
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
    ]
}
```

- esModuleInterop: I needed it to be able to `import seedrandom from 'seedrandom';`
- moduleResolution: was needed for importing from `vue`
- path: needed to not have to import everything with `/@/` but only `@/`
- target: was needed to have gettersand setters in my models (`get x`, `set x`)