# Resolving Vite alias for asset URL instead of local path for CSS images

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-10

I'm trying to get Vite in Laravel to prefix images in CSS such as this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('@/images/background.png');
}
```

With the `ASSET_URL` env value. When I do this config in Vite:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': process.env.ASSET_URL || path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
},
```

I get the error:

```
[vite:css] [postcss] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net/images/background.png'
```

If I remove `process.env.ASSET_URL ||` from that line, then it works fine to alias the image path but that means having the image file in my repo and serving it directly from the server instead of thru CloudFront.

How do I get Vite to just prefix all the `@` entries with the `ASSET_URL` value?

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64504683/13933721

Comment: Try to use `vite-plugin-style-import`

Comment: btw, can you open the image in url `https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net/images/background.png` ?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yes, the URL works when I paste it in my browser. That answer you commented seems to relate to a local path, which I'm not having an issue with. Only have an issue when the path to alias is a URL then it can't find the remote file. I don't want it to find the remote file anyway...I just want it to prefix all the URLs in the CSS with the `ASSET_URL` when there is an `@` sign.

Comment: @KArslan how does that package help? I don't see a use case where it will prefix URLs in CSS with a remote URL instead of just pointing to a local file.

Comment: Instead of an alias, what if you manually use the full path in the asset then `npm run prod` or whatever the command to build assets. Does it still have the same error?

Comment: If it has the same error, then probably vite cant recognize assets from cloudfront during build.

Comment: btw, is the value of `ASSET_URL` = `https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net`? No trailing slash? maybe `url('@/images/background.png');` has `//images` double slashes.

Comment: No trailing slash and the error is exactly as shown, so if I copy the URL from the error and paste it into my browser, it loads the image fine. Statically setting the value to the CloudFront URL produces the same issue. I'd just manually put the `ASSET_URL` in the CSS file if it wasn't for the fact that my local env value and the production env value are different.

Comment: I think I word it wrong. Did you try to use `https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net/images/background.png` in the css then build assets just to check if it would load the image? 2nd, I think the vite config is a JS/TS file, did you try to console.log what the value of `process.env.ASSET_URL` just to confirm the correct path?

Comment: If I manually add that full URL into each `@` placeholder then there is no issue with Vite compiling...it just doesn't dynamically add the correct URL depending on environment.

Comment: This is just a guess but I think vite is unable to recognize assets from external sources. Try to use `--force` flag when building your vite assets. If using npm (e.g. npm run prod), add `--force` inside the value of `prod` key in package.json file

Comment: Or just add plain `--force` if you are using vite command to build.

Comment: Though base on https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html, `--force` is to ignore cache. Does not hurt to try.

Comment: You may try what the answer in this github discussion: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/5997

Comment: so instead of `@`, use a keyword that is only used in `css` that will reference your cdn, such as `url('cssProdCDN/images/background.png');`